# Selecting elements using nth-of-type on every class except the first and last one within multiple divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to select class `can_name` within a card to change the color of the text. But having issues trying to select the proper can_name. I can't even select the first one using either `.can_name:nth-child(1)` or `.can_name:nth-of-type(1)`

As a test/debug I tried

```
.race.candidate .can_name:nth-of-type(1) {
 color:yellow;
}
```

To be able to see if I can just target the first .can_name, but for some reason it targets and changes the yellow color to all the .can_name classes.

Here is the full page code below:

```
<!-- Card #1 -->
<div class="card-body card">
<!-- Within in card #1 Person #1 -->
<div class="race candidate">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="can_name">
            <h5><a>Person 1</a></h5>
                <span class="text-muted">Party</span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- Within in card #1 Person #2 -->
<div class="race candidate">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="can_name">
            <h5><a>Person 2</a></h5>
                <span class="text-muted">Party</span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

<!-- Card #2 -->
<div class="card-body card">

<!-- Within in card #2 Person #1 -->
<div class="race candidate">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="can_name">
            <h5><a>Person 1</a></h5>
                <span class="text-muted">Party</span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- Within in card #2 Person #2 -->
<div class="race candidate">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="can_name">
            <h5><a>Person 2</a></h5>
                <span class="text-muted">Party</span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- Within in card #2 Person #3 -->
<div class="race candidate">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="can_name">
            <h5><a>Person 3</a></h5>
                <span class="text-muted">Party</span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<!-- Card #3     -->
<div class="card-body card">
<!-- Within in card #3 Person #1 -->
<div class="race candidate">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="can_name">
            <h5><a>Person 1</a></h5>
                <span class="text-muted">Party</span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Is it change the `can_name` class of the first `.race` class of each `card` class?

Comment: You have misunderstood how selectors like :nth-child or :nth-of-type work. They affect elements that are _siblings_ - which you don’t have here, _all_ of your elements with the class `can_name` here are the first child _of_ their parent, and the first element of type `div` within their parent as well. You need to perform this kind of selection on the level of your `.race.candidate` elements here - _those_ are actually siblings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you're desired output is. I'm guessing you need the first `can_name` in each card to be `color: yellow`

You have to target the *siblings* of the `card` class and the set color for the *child* `can_name`

You cannot directly target `can_name` because they are **children of different parent divs**

Hope the code below is your intended output.

```css
.race:first-child .can_name {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!-- Card #1 -->
<div class="card-body card">
  <!-- Within in card #1 Person #1 -->
  <div class="race candidate">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="can_name">
            <h5><a>Person 1</a></h5>
            <span class="text-muted">Party</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Within in card #1 Person #2 -->
  <div class="race candidate">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="can_name">
            <h5><a>Person 2</a></h5>
            <span class="text-muted">Party</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Card #2 -->
<div class="card-body card">

  <!-- Within in card #2 Person #1 -->
  <div class="race candidate">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="can_name">
            <h5><a>Person 1</a></h5>
            <span class="text-muted">Party</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Within in card #2 Person #2 -->
  <div class="race candidate">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="can_name">
            <h5><a>Person 2</a></h5>
            <span class="text-muted">Party</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Within in card #2 Person #3 -->
  <div class="race candidate">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="can_name">
            <h5><a>Person 3</a></h5>
            <span class="text-muted">Party</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Card #3     -->
<div class="card-body card">
  <!-- Within in card #3 Person #1 -->
  <div class="race candidate">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="can_name">
            <h5><a>Person 1</a></h5>
            <span class="text-muted">Party</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first tempestive colors everything yellow because nth-type is working this way: it specify a background color for every `.can_name` element that is the first `.can_name` element of its parent. If you need to select a specific card, you need to use something like  `.race.candidate:nth-child(1) .can_name`